# Using ParallelOptions/Multithreading to get data from multiple Oracle DB

Tags: .net, oracle, c#-4.0

I have a requirement to get data from 6 different databases (Oracle 9i, 10G etc) and process the data in 
c# code.

Is there way or is there a sample that demonistrates on how to get the data from DB using ParallelOptions/Multithreading ?

Once I have data I will export that to CSV for further processing.

Comment: Is the data such that your C# application can spawn 6 threads and have each thread process the data from one of the databases?  Or do you need to do something like join tables from 6 different databases before processing the data?

Comment: Like I said, I am getting data from different databases, trying to avoid DBLinks here. Once I have data I will export that to CSV for further processing.

Comment: Yes. Different threads get data from different databases.

Comment: If you can spawn one thread per database, it would seem like you could use basic C# threading and solve the problem in which case I'm not sure what the question is.  Is your question really "How do I implement multiple threads in C#"?

Comment: When you say basic c# threading, how do I use that? any sample?

Comment: A Google search for "C# threading" turns up ~1.5 million results.  This (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx) is the first one-- an MSDN tutorial on threading in C#.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes. I looked at that, I am not sure if there are any modern options available in c# 4. trying to do that in most recent way :)

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not a database problem.  One Oracle database can only talk to another database through a DB Link.  If you don't want to (or can't) use DB links then you need a solution outside of the databases.  Frankly it sounds like you are trying to re-invent SSIS .